# how to make timer inside socket php

Tags: php, sockets, timer

this is the issue, i write a php socket, it work as a daemon, every time, and i have a client side, the client connect but every 30 seconds client automaticaly disconnect, it is happening because socket do not send himself a line (`ka();`) every 30 seconds, the (ka();) line is readed by the client and keep a constant conection, i have tried making a function inside the socket, so every 30 seconds write (ka();), but it does not work, it work wrong, it show the (ka();) if the client send something to the socket, if client side do not send anything the socket do not sent the anything.

the socket work has a daemon CLI windows and the client side is just javascript, when the socket is running, can be accesed directly by navigator and read what client send, if the client do not send anything, the socket need write the (ka();) line, so it is readed by client side and keep conection and so indefinitely.

this is the socket script

```
error_reporting(1);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
define('CON_IP', '127.0.0.1');
define('CON_PORT', 1000);
$socket      = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP);
$max_clients = MAX_CLIENTS;
socket_set_option($socket, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1);
socket_bind($socket, CON_IP, CON_PORT);
socket_listen($socket, $max_clients);
$clients = array(
    '0' => array(
        'socket' => $socket
    )
);
echo "Server running....\n\n";
echo "Server Started on : " . date('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";
echo "Listening on      : " . CON_IP . " port " . CON_PORT . "\n";
echo ".... awaiting connections ...\n\n";
$session = (TRUE);
while ($session === TRUE) {
    $read[0] = $socket;
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($clients) + 1; ++$i) {
        if ($clients[$i] != NULL) {
            $read[$i + 1] = $clients[$i]['socket'];
        }
    }
    $ready = socket_select($read, $write = NULL, $except = NULL, $tv_sec = NULL);
    if (in_array($socket, $read)) {
        for ($i = 1; $i < $max_clients + 1; ++$i) {
            if (!isset($clients[$i])) {
                $clients[$i]['socket'] = socket_accept($socket);
                socket_getpeername($clients[$i]['socket'], $RemoteAddr, $RemotePort);
                $clients[$i]['ipadd'] = $RemoteAddr . ':' . $RemotePort;
                echo 'Incoming connection from ' . $clients[$i]['ipadd'] . "]\r\n";
                break;
            } elseif ($i == $max_clients - 1) {
                echo 'Clients Overload!' . "\r\n";
            }
            if ($ready < 1) {
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
    for ($i = 1; $i < $max_clients + 1; ++$i) {
        if (in_array($clients[$i]['socket'], $read)) {
            if (!$client[$i]['iframe']) {
                $data = @socket_read($clients[$i]['socket'], 1024, PHP_BINARY_READ);
            }
            if (substr($data, 0, 3) == 'GET' || substr($data, 0, 4) == 'POST' || substr($data, 0, 4) == 'OPTI') {
                $clients[$i]['iframe'] = true;
                echo 'Incoming connection from browser [' . $clients[$i]['ipadd'] . "]\r\n";
                socket_write($clients[$i]['socket'], "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
                socket_write($clients[$i]['socket'], "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8;\r\n");
                socket_write($clients[$i]['socket'], "Cache-Control: private\r\n\r\n");
                for ($z = 0; $z < 4096; $z++)
                $Brk = ("\n");
                $html = ('<!DOCTYPE html>' . $Brk);
                $html .= ('<html>' . $Brk);
                $html .= ('<head>' . $Brk);
                $html .= ('</head>' . $Brk);
                $html .= ('<body>' . $Brk);
                $html .= ('<script>' . $Brk);
                $html .= ('function recv(packets){}' . $Brk);
                $html .= ('</script>' . $Brk);
                $html .= ('</body>' . $Brk);
                socket_write($clients[$i]['socket'], $html);
            } else {
                if (trim($data) != '' && strlen(str_replace(' ', '', trim($data))) > 1) {
                        $msgs = ($data);
                }
            }
            if ($data === FALSE) {
                echo 'Incoming disconnection of ' . $clients[$i]['ipadd'] . "]\r\n";
                unset($clients[$i]);
                continue;
            }
            $data = trim($data);
            if (!empty($data)) {
                //LOGS
                if ($msgs) {
                    $ClientDumpLog = fopen('log/InputToSocket.txt', "a");
                    fwrite($ClientDumpLog, "$msgs\n");
                    fclose($ClientDumpLog);
                }
                //
                for ($j = 1; $j < $max_clients + 1; ++$j) {
                    if (isset($clients[$j]['socket']) and ($msgs !== NULL)) {
                        echo ('[' . $clients[$i]['ipadd'] . '] OK!' . "\r\n");
                        socket_write($clients[$j]['socket'], '<script>' . $msgs . "</script>\r\n");
                    }
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

this solution, i think it was, but no, this code block, to test, writed after this line:

```
for ($j = 1; $j < $max_clients + 1; ++$j) {


    $last_time = time();
while(true) {
if(time()-$last_time > 10) {
  echo ('[' . $clients[$i]['ipadd'] . '] KA!' . "\r\n");
  socket_write($clients[$j]['socket'], "ka();\r\n");
 $last_time = time();
 }
}
```

when i put this code, when the socket start, it show every (chosed time) in cli (KA!), when i access by navigator it show the (ka();) line too, but when the client side send something it never show, is like the (ka) line or what the client send, but no both at the same time.
somebody know some function or solution to make it work?

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the maximum execution time setting of php.ini. You should not change it within php.ini - you rather should change it on top of your code:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
//... your fancy code here...
```